# laravel post for image and textfield

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The post created is to save the image and description to the DB but only the description gets saved.The request is being done via formData()..So currently trying via postman

```php
$post = new Post;
$post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$post->desc = $request->desc;

//check if post has photo
If($request->hasFile('image')){
  $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  
  $request->image->move('storage/posts', $imageName);
  $post->photo = $imageName ;
}

//mistake
$post->save();
$post->user;
return response()->json([
  'success' => true,
  'message' => 'posted',
  'post' => $post
]);
```

Comment: How are you uploading the image? Is it a POST request via an html `<form>`? Or is it an AJAX request using `FormData()`? Please provide more information. It's likely that `$request->file('image')` is `null`. Also, you're missing a `)`: `If($request->hasFile('image'){` should be `if($request->hasFile('image')) { ... }`

Comment: Question Updated Please

Comment: show your formData code as well

Comment: Yeah, I meant show the code you're using to do the upload...

Comment: I'm currently using postman to test the API,but i get same issue

Answer (score 0):

1_check directory has permission 777

2_$request->file('image')->move("directory", "new file name");

```
   if($request->file('image') !=null){

$request->file('image')->move("directory", "new file name")
}
```